# Function won't progress past the end of the for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, google-apps-script

I am certain that there is something simple here that I am missing. This portion of code is on the client-side of my site:

```
function test(){
var insert;
var insertArray = [];
var arrayLength = document.getElementById("arrayLength").value;
var length = parseInt(arrayLength)
var o;
var int;
var insertID
var i;


for (i = 0; i<=length; i++){
   int = i.toString();
   insertID = "insertNumber" + int;
   insert = document.getElementById(insertID).value;
   insertArray.push(insert);
};

o = JSON.stringify(insertArray);

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(successDisplay)
  .mailroomDataEntry(o);

}
```

The loop works as it should, however the function does not seem to be progressing beyond the end of the loop. No data is being passed back over to the server-side.

For example, if I put `window.alert(insertArray)` inside the for loop I get the expected results (i.e. one alert box each time the loop progresses until the final box has the completed array.

However, if I put the same window.alert after the for loop's closure, I get nothing. No alert box at all.

Comment: Is it throwing any console errors? Are you certain that `length` is the value you are expecting?

Comment: I started to say that the length was exactly what I was expecting, as it was 93 and there are 93 items currently in the array...then I realized that for 93  items the I actually need 92 to be the value of length. Changed: var length = parseInt(arrayLength) to var length = parseInt(arrayLength)-1 and works perfectly. 

Thanks so much for your help. I was sure it was something simple!

Comment: Put a `try{` under your variable definitions, and at the very end `} catch(e) {console.log('There was an error: ' + e.message)}`  The variable `insertArray` may not be valid JSON.  But, the only way to know what is happening is to do some debugging.  For Chrome and Firefox hit the f12 key to open up the browser console.

Comment: Does the elements iDs start at insertNumber0 or insertNumber1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to samanime I realized the the variable `length` had the incorrect value.

Changed:

```
for (i = 0; i<=length; i++)
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i<length; i++)
```

and it works just fine. Thanks samanime!

**Edited per Lars de Bruijn's comment. Thanks Lars de Bruijn.

Comment: Probably a cleaner solution would be to rewrite your for loop to `for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {` rather than subtracting from the length. Notice the `<` "smaller than" rather than the `<=` "smaller than or equal to"

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks so much!